# Can someone help translating "one must die for one to live"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, sentence-translation

I'm writing a novel and at some point, the hero needs to make a sacrifice: "One must die for one to live." He has to chose between two people: only one will survive, the other one will die. (I'm being specific because Google translation thought I was talking about love.) Could you please help me translate this phrase please?

> One must die for one to live.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

One possibility:

> *necesse est alterum mori ut alter vivat.*
> It's necessary that one (of the two) die in order that the other live.

A variation:

> *ut alter vivat necesse est ut alter moriatur.*
> In order that one (of the two) may live, it's necessary that the other die.

Comment: Your first option sounds very natural, compared to the second one, which involves a marked simultaneous combination of two _ut_-clauses that are grammatically different.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another, more concise option:

> Alteri moriendum ut alter vivat.

This uses a different way of expressing "must" than cnread's translations, but means basically the same thing. You could also change the word order to *Alteri moriendum ut vivat alter* if you like the sound of that better -- Latin has lots of ways of expressing any given idea!

Comment: I agree that a relevant virtue of your option is that it is more concise than _necesse est alterum mori ut alter vivat_. However, a virtue of the latter is that it is not ambiguous compared to your option: grammatically speaking, _alteri_ can be a dative of agent (intended reading) but could also be a beneficiary dative. Cf. the less classical construction _Pugnandum habebam non imperatori tantum sed patri_ (Sen. _Con._ 10.2.4), which was probably used by Seneca to avoid the ambiguity of the more classical construction _(Mihi) pugnandum erat non imperatori tantum sed patri_.

Comment: I do like the chiasm in your second option.

Comment: @Mitomino Syntactically ambiguous, perhaps, but what would *alicui morior* actually mean?

Comment: The ambiguity could arise in cases where _mori_ + dative is used agentively, like _pugnare_ + dative above: 'to die/to fight for someone', e.g. for the emperor.

Comment: @Mitomino But are there such cases of *mori* + dat.? I'd expect *mori pro* + abl. instead. I doubt it would occur to any Classical Latin speaker to read *alteri* as anything other than a dative of agent.

Comment: @TKR Both patterns (beneficiary dative and  _pro_ + ablative) can alternate to express the same content: e.g. cf. _qui sciret sibi pro omnibus suis pugnandum_ (Frontin. _strat._ 1.11.5) and _Pugnandum habebam non imperatori tantum sed patri_ (Sen. _Con._ 10.2.4). Is this alternation possible with _pugnandum_ but not with _moriendum_? Or, to be more precise, is _Pugnandum est imperatori_ ambiguous, whereas _Moriendum est imperatori_ is not? Well, I don't think so (as noted, for me both are ambiguous). Was there variation on this point among native speakers? Well, perhaps, but we'll never know.

Comment: The fact that _pugnare_ but not _mori_ can be easily found with a beneficiary dative is because the former is an agentive unergative verb, whereas the latter is a non-agentive unaccusative verb. However, as noted above, _mori_ can also be used agentively (not only in Latin but also in other languages) and it is only in this non-prototypical usage when this verb can be expected to coappear with a beneficiary dative (hence your correct impression above concerning the rarity of this pattern). So _imperatori_ can be a beneficiary dative in _Moriendum est imperatori_ if _mori_ is used agentively.

Comment: @Mitomino Well, maybe it's not impossible (though I'd like to see attestations), but pragmatically speaking the beneficiary reading seems pretty unlikely -- "(some unspecified person) must die for one so that the other will live"? Lots of theoretical ambiguities are visible only to syntacticians. *Time flies like an arrow, but fruit flies like a banana*.

Comment: To avoid this problem with pragmatics, I deliberately changed your example into another one where both readings of the dative (agent and benef.) can sound natural: _Moriendum est imperatori_. According to you, this example is NOT ambiguous (unlike _Pugnandum est imperatori_), right? On second thought, perhaps you're right & I'm wrong: the lack of ambiguity of _Moriendum est imperatori_ would be coherent with the ungrammaticality of _Moriendum est ab omnibus_, discussed in https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/on-the-alleged-passive-meaning-of-so-called-miscalled-passive-periphrastic

Comment: @Mitomino I don't have a clear sense of whether *Moriendum est imperatori* can have a beneficiary reading; I'd want to do a corpus search for examples of *mori* + dat. with such a reading. (If there are none, of course that wouldn't be probative, but it would be suggestive.)

Comment: I like Alteri moriendum ut vivat alter. Beautiful.
And while we're being linguistically finicky, I wish people would stop saying "compared to" when they mean "compared with." The first marks a similarity, as in "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day," the second a difference.

Comment: @user14904 This does not add anything to existing answers, except a prescriptivist claim about an artificial difference between two English structures that are not relevant to the question at all.

Comment: @user14904 If you're taking about Mitomono's comment, do bear in mind that English isn't everyone's first language, and languages change all the time. For what it's worth, that's how I would use those two.

Answer (score 4):

In Italian we use the concise latin expression *mors tua, vita mea* to describe self-defence (both literal or figurative).

In your case you may want to adjust the pronouns - *mors alicuius, vita alius*  or similarly.

Comment: Or _mors alterius, vita alterius_, which has a nice parallelism to it.